# Validate captcha using jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have an application form in which i need to validate captcha using jquery. IF the captcha entered is wrong then an alert box as to displayed please enter captcha again the entered captcha is wrong.. How can i does this using jquery.. Please help me i m new to jquery.

Here is the code

```
 $(function() {
        $("#XISubmit").click(function(){
    $(document).ready(function(){
$("#XIForm").submit(function(event) {
event.preventDefault()
val=$('#vercode').val()
$.ajax({
        type:"post",
        url:"verify-captcha.php",
        data:{'code':val},
        success:function(data){
                 if(data=='false'){
                alert('Re-enter Captcha, You Entered wrong captcha code')
                $("#cap").html("<img  src='captcha.php'>"); }
                            else{  $("#XIForm").unbind('submit')}
                            }

        });                   
});

});


            document.getElementById("XIForm").submit();

                });

    <label>Security Validation</label>  

      <label>Security Validation</label>    

 <span><img   src="captcha.php"></span><input type="text" name="vercode" id="vercode" size="10" style="margin-top: -1px; float: left; width: 115px; margin-right: 12px;"></li><div id="msg"></div>

    captcha.php

    <?php
session_start();
$ranStr = md5(microtime());
$ranStr = substr($ranStr, 0, 6);
$_SESSION['cap_code'] = $ranStr;
$newImage = imagecreatefromjpeg("cap_bg.jpg");
$txtColor = imagecolorallocate($newImage, 0, 0, 0);
imagestring($newImage, 5, 5, 5, $ranStr, $txtColor);
header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
imagejpeg($newImage);
?>



verify-captcha.php
<?php
session_start(); 
if ($_POST["code"] != $_SESSION["cap_code"] || $_SESSION["cap_code"]=='')  { 
 echo 'false';
}else{
echo 'true';}
```

Comment: For this, you will need CAPTCHA value in javascript. But then an attacker can read this value and bypass CAPTCHA. So it makes CAPTCHA protection useless.

Comment: @mesutozer XHR? Hash?

Comment: @bjb568 did not think XHR was an option? What did you mean by Hash?

Comment: @mesutozer Why wouldn't XHR be an option? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function

Comment: It is definitely an option but I could not think of that. I know what Hash means but I could not understand how it is relevant in this context?

Answer (score 0):

Html code

```
<span><img   src="captcha.php"></span><input type="text" name="vercode" id="vercode" size="10" style="margin-top: -1px; float: left; width: 115px; margin-right: 12px;"></li><div id="msg"></div>
```

Code for captcha.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$ranStr = md5(microtime());
$ranStr = substr($ranStr, 0, 6);
$_SESSION['cap_code'] = $ranStr;
$newImage = imagecreatefromjpeg("cap_bg.jpg");
$txtColor = imagecolorallocate($newImage, 0, 0, 0);
imagestring($newImage, 5, 5, 5, $ranStr, $txtColor);
header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
imagejpeg($newImage);
?>
```

Jquery code for captcha

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#form").submit(function(event) {
event.preventDefault()
val=$('#vercode').val()
$.ajax({
        type:"post",
        url:"verify-captcha.php",
        data:{'code':val},
        success:function(data){
                 if(data=='false'){
                alert('Re-enter Captcha, You Entered wrong captcha code')
                $("#cap").html("<img  src='captcha.php'>"); }
                            else{  $("#form").unbind('submit')}
                            }

        });                   
});

});
```

Code for verify-captcha.php

```
<?php
session_start(); 
if ($_POST["code"] != $_SESSION["cap_code"] || $_SESSION["cap_code"]=='')  { 
 echo 'false';
}else{
echo 'true';}
```

Comment: captcha regeneration can be bypassed here. Old captcha should be invalidated by an unsuccesful attempt.

Comment: Its not working. The form gets submitted without entering the captcha code. Here is the edited code.